# Criteria to choose between x86 and x64 when building for Azure web sites

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I read that `Any CPU` indicates `Microsoft.NET` to compile the IL to the architecture of the running Windows system (either x86 or x64).

I also read different sorts of suggestions - some people favor x86, some others x64, with different accounts of performance results.

My question is - in the case of Azure web sites, what should be the criteria to decide on x86, x64 and Any CPU? Thank you.

Comment: You should look at [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/567987/32bits-or-64bits-for-windows-azure-web-sites) on ServerFault to see the answers are what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VM in Azure App Service are x64. 32-bit app will run just fine on a x64 machine.

Your question is more about 32bit app vs 64bit app. IMO, unless your application require larger address space, 32bit might be better choice since it normally use less memory.